# Python memory consumption: How to clear memory from process?

Tags: python, pyodbc

I have code to query SQL using pyodbc :

```
    import pyodbc
    import gc

    with pyodbc.connect(connection_string) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        tmp = list(cursor.execute(query))
        # attempt to clear cursor memory
        cursor.close()
        cursor = None
        gc.collect()
```

The issue I'm encountering is that I can't clear memory from this process:

[image]

Even when I close the jupyter notebook I'm running the script from, it hangs out in memory. I can right click and press "end task" , but I need it automated (and this brute force way requires a computer restart).

Also, I had to manually configure the memory settings by setting a "max memory per instance" (to 2500MB), this slowed down the query times a lot, and ideally I could have infinite memory, but clear process memory after each SQL query.

Comment: how do you know pyodbc is causing the issue?  the fact that closing the connection and closing out of Jupyter without effect suggests your memory hog lies somewhere else

Comment: SQL Server does not generally release memory back to the OS, but it does re-use the memory it already has.  What are you worried about?  The SQL Server process should not grow by this amount every time you run your script. This is NOT a memory leak - it is a server process allocating memory to do as you requested.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pyodbc
import gc

with pyodbc.connect(connection_string) as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    tmp = list(cursor.execute(query))
    # attempt to clear cursor memory
    cursor.close()
    del cursor
    gc.collect()
```

Comment: This would only affect the memory used by the *client* process. The question is about the memory consumed by the *server* process. They are different things.